# dropdown for particular column in ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular

I am using `ng2-smart-table` for my `angular 4` application. Is it possible to use dropdown for particular column while adding a new row? That dropdown displays data from database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use dropdown for perticular column.

**Setting**

```
role: {
  title: 'Title',
  type: 'html',
  editor: {
    type: 'list', // Used to set dropdown list from database. 
    config: {
      list: [

      ],
    },
  },
  filter: true
}
```

`getData` from database by call API.

```
getData(){
  this.userListSettings.columns.role.editor.config.list = []; // Clear role list 
  var settingList: any = [];
  // Call API Hear 
  settingList.push({ value: {SET VALUE}, title: {SET TITLE} });

  let newSettings = this.Settings;
  newSettings.columns.role.editor.config.list = settingList;
  this.userListSettings = Object.assign({}, newSettings);
}
```

Comment: Could you help, my dropdown isn't get populated I'm not seeing the result loaded from Database.